# SQL Get char at position in field

Tags: sql

How can I get the character at position 4 in a field?

e.g.

field contents = "hello"

I want to return the value of position 2 = "l"

Comment: You should provide the DBMS you're using (mysql/mssql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite/...) when asking sql-related questions (best to add the appropriate tag). Not providing it is like asking how to format a flash drive without telling what your operating system is.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('hello', 3, 1)
```

Take care: index is 1-based.

Answer (score 10):

In Oracle, use SUBSTR

Syntax is `SUBSTR(<string to parse>,<start position>,(<length>))` - i.e.

```
SELECT SUBSTR('hello',3,1)
```

Start position and length are one-, not zero-based. Zero is accepted, but will be interpreted as 1.

Answer (score 2):

following Query will search from specific index for char and will return result

```
select * from tbPatientMaster
where SUBSTRING (fname,CHARINDEX ('.',fname,0)+1,LEN (fname)) like 'a%'
```