# PostgreSQL: How to extract text from a particular letter?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, substring

I'm practicing exercises with SQL and I've got a problem I couldn't resolve yet.

I have a table with a column named: **'email' ** and I want to extract just the Domain of each mail. Then I was thinking to extract since '@' to get that information.

But idk how to do it, was trying with SUBSTRING, but that didn't work because that's about position, and each mail has different size.

I attach a screenshot about the table's composition (does not contain real information). Thank u so much :)

[image]

I tried with SUBSTRING method but that didn't work
Example email:  example_email@outlook.com
Output expected: @outlook.com

Comment: `mysql` and `postgresql` are completely different databases, using different syntax for (at least) some functions. Please only specify the DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: Please show the statement that you where (trying) to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Get char at position in field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409822/sql-get-char-at-position-in-field)

Comment: Hmmz, it should have been this post which is making this a duplicatie: [MYSQL : Find the last occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276940/mysql-find-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `SPLIT_PART` to fetch everything after the @ and then append the @:

```
SELECT CONCAT('@',SPLIT_PART(email, '@', 2)) AS mailDomain
FROM people_practice;
```

Here the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) about this and other useful string functions.

Comment: Wooo! It really worked! Thank you sooo much!  :) I didn't know about the 'split part' method.